# collocation: idol to or of?

Tags: prepositions, collocations

I'd like to know which preposition should be used in the following:

> 1. John is **an** idol **of** / **to** many teenagers.
> 2. John is **the** idol **of** / **to** many teenagers.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: This is not really a collocation.

Comment: Is your question about the use of articles? It's unclear what you're asking because you've bolded both the articles and the prepositions.

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

> After her parents died in the crash, her uncle was father and mother *to* her.

There, **to** expresses the idea "in regard to her". He is not her own father. He is in the *role* of father and mother.

The preposition **of** on the other hand expresses the concept of "possession", broadly construed.

> He is the father of those rambunctious boys.

So, to be an idol *to* someone expresses a role relationship.

> He was an idol to them.

They regarded him as an idol.  They looked to him as one looks to an idol. The admired-admirer relationship is foregrounded.

> He was the idol of millions.

There, the "possessive" aspect is foregrounded, again *possession* broadly construed. Each of those millions might say "He is *my* idol".

So these are not competing collocations but the expression of different ideas.

Answer (score 0):

John is an idol to many teenagers.

John is the idol of many teenagers.

Technically, you can also say, John is the idol to many teenagers, if you want to say that John is THE ultimate idol.